# Jersey 2.23 with multiple servlets and @Context issues

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

## My scenario

I have an application where we are using two different servlets for two different API versions (v1 & v2).

My web.xml contains the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>v2-jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.demo.rest.service.RestApiConfigV2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>105</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>v2-jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/v2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>v1-jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.demo.rest.service.RestApiConfigV1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>106</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>v1-jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/v1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So, I have two different `ResourceConfig` classes that I use to register each servlet. This configs share a ContainerRequestFilter (eventually will do authentication). It's defined as the following:

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@Component
@Provider
public class MyRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
```

My config classes look like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class RestApiConfigV2 extends ResourceConfig {

     public RestApiConfigV2() {
         register(MyRequestFilter.class);
         register(ResourceServiceV2.class); // REST API resource
     }
}

@Configuration
public class RestApiConfigV1 extends ResourceConfig {

     public RestApiConfigV1() {
         register(MyRequestFilter.class);
         register(ResourceServiceV1.class); // REST API resource
     }
}
```

## The problem

The primary issue here is that Jersey seems to be spinning up both servlets and mapping the endpoints correctly, but my `MyRequestFilter` is causing an issue related to the use of `@Context private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;` What happens is **only one of the REST API endpoints (v1 or v2) will end up getting to use the ContainerRequestFilter** while the other ones faces an error in regards to accessing the HttpServletRequest. The error I'm getting in the tomcat logs is the following:

```
ERROR 2017-08-04 00:14:27,908 T[http-apr-8080-exec-8] Runtime Exception Occurredjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.current(RequestScope.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:158)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.MethodInterceptorImpl.internalInvoke(MethodInterceptorImpl.java:89) 
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.MethodInterceptorImpl.invoke(MethodInterceptorImpl.java:125)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.MethodInterceptorInvocationHandler.invoke(MethodInterceptorInvocationHandler.java:62)
```

Any time the `servletRequest` object is accessed, it throws this exception. This is strange behavior, and not what I expected. I would hope that I would be able to properly inject the servlet request via `@Context`

## What I've Tried

I have tried to avoid the request scope issue by making my filter use the `@Scope("request")` but this doesn't work, and I think it's related to the fact that I'm autowiring non-request scoped beans in the filter bean (which is request scoped). So, that didn't work.

I also tried to remove the v1 servlet from web.xml and tear it out from Jersey registering it, leaving only the v2 servlet enabled. This makes the authentication filter work!

So, the issue is related to two different servlets, both using the same `ContainerRequestFilter` and the class that implements it needs to inject the context of the servlet request.

Am I doing something wrong here? Shouldn't this just work? I have to meet the use case of two different servlets, since we are using special responses for each REST API version.

Comment: Why is the ResourceConfig annotated with `@Configuration`?

Comment: Right, that's unnecessary. I forgot to remove it, I was playing around with attempting to auto-wire the filter. I know this is wrong.

Comment: Try also removing the `@Component` from the filter. It's not needed. Even if you wanted to `@Autowired` Spring services into the filter, the annotation is still not needed. The filter doesn't need to be a Spring component to be able to inject other Spring components into it.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks! Still have the same issue, but I'm glad to have learned that

Comment: Might be something wrong with some configuration you're not showing us. I put together a POC that works just fine. See the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-two-apps)

Comment: I think the configuration is very finicky. I swapped the order of the filter / resource configuration, and it all of a sudden works. I did this since I saw that's what you did in your POC. In addition, I removed all `@Component` / `@Configuration` as you noted was wrong and unnecessary.